# jQuery live issue - undefined not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a live search with ajax and im getting a console log error of `Uncaught Typeerror: undefined is not a function.` The error points me to the first line of the code. Ive used this before and it worked no idea whats going on now, any ideas?

```
$("input#search-staff").live("keyup", function() {
        // Set Search String
        var staffname = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if(staffname !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "_ajax/_tasks/search-staff.php",
                data: { query: staffname },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#staff-list").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that element `$("input#search-staff")` exists in DOM?

Comment: [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Consider using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead

Comment: hundo p it exists in the dom

Comment: jQuery.live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Use .on insted!

Comment: switching to .on seemed to fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your function *could* look like:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input#search-staff", function(e) {
    var staffname = $(this).val();

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!staffname) return;

    $.get("_ajax/_tasks/search-staff.php", {query: staffname})
    .done(function (html) {
        $("ul#staff-list").html(html);
    });
});
```

Notes

- switch from `.live()` to `.on()` event delegation
- return early - less deeply nested code
- switch from `.ajax()` to `.get()` with jqXhr deferred event handler (`.done()`)

P.S.: Try not to do things like `cache: false` on the client side. Simply set the appropriate HTTP caching directives in the response headers (`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`) and leave the client at the default.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in version 1.7 and removed from jQuery 1.9.
Use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) insted.